# Is earning money haram through selling computer hashing power?

Tags: halal-haram, money

**First of all please don't mark it as duplicate because:**

1. From many questions related to Bitcoin/Altcoin, I did not find
   solution for "earning through selling computer hashing power"
2. My question about "selling computer hashing power", not using or
   investing in Bitcoin/Altcoin

I bought high-end computer few months ago (16-core processor + 3 GPUs). So, I thought selling hashing power (to Nicehash / zpool) as passive income would be good idea. But recently I came to know that scholars gave their opinions about Bitcoin/Altcoin as "Stay away from it", "It does not have intrinsic value, so not halal" etc.

I already earned $700 by selling hashing power (lost $180 since Nicehash got hacked recently)

***So, please explain "Is it haram to earn by selling computer hashing power?" (I am ok with makhruh)***

***And if haram, what to do with already earned money ?***

Comment: I mentioned that It's not about investing in Bitcoin/Altcoin and still marked as a duplicate?.